# Implementing Iterator for generic types

Tags: rust

I want to implement iterator on very simple structure with `Vec<T>`;
I expect it to looks like that:

```
struct GenericIter<T> {
  vec: Vec<T>,
  i: usize
}
```

Where `i` is a counter for iterator.

Basic implementation would looks like that:

```
impl<T> Iterator for GenericIter<T> {
  type Item = T;

  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    if self.i >= self.vec.len() {
      return None;
    }

    self.i += 1;

    Some(self.vec[self.i - 1])
  }
}
```

But compiler will tell:
cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<T>`

move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` traitrustc(E0507)
main.rs(30, 14): move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Ok, if I'm going to try to implement `Copy` trait like that

```
struct GenericIter<T> where T: Copy {
  vec: Vec<T>,
  i: usize
}
```

I have another error from compiler which tells:
the trait bound `T: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied

the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `T`rustc(E0277)

How can I reach my original goal and have Iterator implemented with Vector with generic values in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators return their items **owned**. So if you want to both return parts of `vec` through the iterator and simultaneously keep it stored in your `struct`, they need to be copyable.

If you don't want to copy them, you need to stop storing them in the struct after they are returned.

There are several ways I could think of that solve this problem:

- Store them optionally: `Vec<Option<T>>`
- Store them in a data structure that can be popped from the front: `VecDeque<T>`

First, the `Vec<Option<T>>`:

```
struct GenericIter<T> {
    vec: Vec<Option<T>>,
    i: usize,
}

impl<T> Iterator for GenericIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.i >= self.vec.len() {
            return None;
        }

        self.i += 1;

        Some(self.vec[self.i - 1].take().unwrap())
    }
}
```

Although I would refactor it a little to prevent the `unwrap()`.

```
struct GenericIter<T> {
    vec: Vec<Option<T>>,
    i: usize,
}

impl<T> Iterator for GenericIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let result = self.vec.get_mut(self.i).and_then(Option::take);
        self.i += 1;
        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    let iter = GenericIter::<u32> {
        vec: vec![Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)],
        i: 0,
    };

    for el in iter {
        println!("{}", el);
    }
}
```

```
1
2
3
```

---

Second, the solution with `VecDeque<T>`:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

struct GenericIter<T> {
    vec: VecDeque<T>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for GenericIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.vec.pop_front()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let iter = GenericIter::<u32> {
        vec: VecDeque::from([1, 2, 3]),
    };

    for el in iter {
        println!("{}", el);
    }
}
```

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: 3) Using `drain()`.

Comment: How so? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: My problem, not `drain()`, `IntoIter` (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bca47569a5db9e9f45969a890c7a68d5). Now you probably don't even need `GenericIter`.

Comment: Sure :) I just assumed that OPs code was a minimal toy version of a more complex one. But yes, this might all be an XY problem.